# Compile single SASS file with all variables and mixins it relies on

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, mixins, scss-mixins

I have a very specific need: I want to apply part of a SASS code from `Project A` into `Project B`. For that to happen, I need to bundle, in a single file, all variables and mixins which are referenced from a specific file.

Let's say the `.scss` portion of `Project A` that needs to be exported is called `_header.scss`. That file contains the exact chunk of code I need to apply and reuse in `Project B`.

Now, the challenge is that `_header.scss` uses several variables and mixins which are defined in global `_variables.scss` and `_mixins.scss` files. `_header.scss` doesn't use all the variables and mixins defined in the project, just a smaller set of them.

Therefore, I would like to run a gulp, yarn or node command to grab `_header.scss`, read the variables and mixins it relies on and compile an output file (`_header-compiled.whatever.scss`) that includes the mixins and variables it depends on, as well as the SASS code itself.

Which command shall I execute to run this check and output everything I need in `Project B` in a single file?

If you think there is an overall better solution for me to use than doing this type of compilation, please, feel free to suggest.

Many thanks in advance!